# Retain Enum values in sharepoint web part on update-spsolution

Tags: enums, sharepoint-2010

We built a visual web part with an enum as a custom property to allow a user to select a theme for a button. The theme list is alphabetical.

We now have new themes to add to the web part, but if we just update the enum list of themes adding new items between the existing values in the web part, anyone who is using this web part may get a different theme based on the enum value.

I've posted the code below, but I guess I'm looking for advice on how to best update a solution and keep the existing values for people using the web part.

Existing

public enum ButtonThemes
        //these choices link to images in the /_layouts/images/MWHCallToAction directory eg Brown.jpg the any new images choices should be added here and the actual images uploaded to the server.

```
    {
            None,
            Announcement,
            ApprovedSoftware,           
            ComputerMouse
         }
New Enum could be 
  public enum ButtonThemes
        //these choices link to images in the /_layouts/images/MWHCallToAction directory eg Brown.jpg the any new images choices should be added here and the actual images uploaded to the server. 
        {
            None,
            Announcement,
            Attention,
            ApprovedSoftware,           
            ComputerMouse,
            DollarSign,
            Email,
            HelpDesk
        }
  //button theme (the type of image shown to teh left of the grey button text)
        [DefaultValue(ButtonThemes.Announcement)]
        [Description("Select the theme for the button.")]
        [WebBrowsable(true)]
        [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
        [Category("Button Properties")]
        public ButtonThemes ButtonTheme
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

In this example if someone is using the Approved Software theme - but we add 'Attention' before it,then their theme could automatically be 'Attention' in the web part when we update the solution.

We could add the new values after the current ones, but looking for something more elegant.

Cheers
Rich

Answer (score 0):

fixed it.

Assign a value to each enum item and its all ok so

```
None,
Announcement = 1,
ApprovedSoftware = 2,
Attention = 4,           
ComputerMouse = 3
```

Hope this helps.